# PHP alter URL without redirecting to it?

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I alter url or part of it using php? I lost the code that I have used and now I cannot find answer online.

I know using `header('Location: www.site.com')` gets redirect but how can I just show fake URL?

I don't want to use mod_rewrite now.

Comment: You have to dramatically improve your question, adding background story and particular example of what you want to get. Otherwise it will be closed.

Comment: So for example you want the user to be on www.fakebank.example.com but think they're on www.theirbank.example.com? Not a chance, sorry.

Comment: Do you want to become **hacker**?

Comment: Btw, the Location header takes the protocol, www.site.com will redirect to http://yourdomain.com/www.site.com ;-)

Comment: you can only do this on the host of a computer, hosts file and what not.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible in PHP, which is executed server side. Any change to the url you make will trigger a page loading.

I think it may be possible in javascript, but I really doubt this is a good idea, if you want to rewrite an url only in the user adressbar, you're doing something wrong, or bad ;)

Comment: No i am just trying to not use mod rewrite and rather make seo friendly url with php... it hink it woked once i might be wrong.
You know like with mod_rewrite there is way to show one extension like index.html but feed from index.php i looking to do same with php

Comment: is catching '404-page not found' what you think of? (in the sense of redirecting the 'page' not found to a controller)

Answer (score 0):

What you've actually asked for isn't possible in using PHP (Although, in JavaScript you can use the [dreadful hashbang](http://www.isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) or the poorly supported bleeding edge [pushState](http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2011/2/2/degradable-javascript-applications-using-html5-pushstate)).

However, in a comment on another answer you stated that your goal is actually friendly URIs without mod_rewrite. This isn't about showing a different URI to the real one, but about making a URI that isn't based on a simple set of files and directories.

This **is** usually achieved (in PHP-land) with mod_rewrite, so you should probably stick with that approach.

However, you can do it using ScriptAlias (assuming you use Apache, other webservers may have different approaches).

e.g. `ScriptAlias /example /var/www/example.php` in the Apache configuration.

Then in the PHP script you can read `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to find out what is requested and pull in the appropriate content.

Answer (score 0):

You can make somewhat SEO-friendly URLs by adding directories after the php script name so that your URLs become:

http://yoursite.com/script.php/arg1/arg2

In script.php:

```
<?php

$args = preg_split('#/#', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);

echo "arg1 = ".$args[1].", arg2 = ".$args[2]."\n";

?>
```

if you use some more htaccess trickery, then you can make the script.php look like something else (see @David's answer for an idea)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using,

`file_get_contents("https://website.com");`

This is not going to redirect but fire the api and you can catch the output by assigning a variable to above function.