# yii2 - urlmanager and changing browser url

Tags: url, redirect, browser, yii2, yii-url-manager

Is it possible with Yii2 change the browser url using the urlManager config?

Or am I supposed to use only:

```
 Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(Url::to([...]));
```

in the controller#action?

Example:

Controller Topic, Controller Reply.

Url => topic/1/reply => controllerB#index(topic_id)
...

Url => reply/1 or reply/create|view|update 
=> 
reply/index page (and browser url changed)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't think so. Not a Yii-restriction, rather how PHP and your webserver process a request.

Seems to be plenty of similar questions... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132196/change-response-url-without-redirect) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115894/php-alter-url-without-redirecting-to-it).